# Word to describe an engraved slogan or name for charity purposes?

Tags: word-choice

I'm doing a fundraiser that allows a user to memorialize content, be it a phrase, picture, or emblem among other content with fixed dimensions (height & width).

Historically, people inscribed words into brass plates, names into cornerstones, or bricks.  The Walk of fame could be considered something similar.

- Is there a word to describe this overall concept?

The word *engraving* doesn't imply the charitable nature, nor the fact it will co-exist with other *engravings*, nor the elite status the engraving represents.

Ideally there is a way to contrast the visual consistency (Hollywood boulevard) in contrast to the sponsor-defined engravings of a chair/bench in Bryant Park, vs a sponsor wall which may have little or no visual consistency.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for *dedication*.

The third definition given by Merriam-Webster is

[**Dedication**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dedication)   *noun*

> the act of officially saying that something (such as a new building) was created for a particular purpose (such as worship) or to remember or honor a particular person

Comment: Can a dedication apply to both living or dead people?  My gut instinct is that dedication is for the deceased, but that may be based on limited personal experience.

Comment: @makerofthings7 Yes. You can have a dedication to a living person. Books, for example, are frequently dedicated to the living.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "commemorative donations" will work.  It seems to be used by other charities soliciting money and offering some way to memorialize content from the donor.  I believe you will want to use some derivation of the word "commemoration."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commemorate

Perhaps "commemoration for charity" would work.

Here are sites soliciting money using the term "commemorative donations" (the first stresses that "It is regretted that money donated cannot be used for the provision of an individual personalised tree or seat," but the others stress the personalization of the sort you mention):

http://bradgatepark.org/memorial/commemorative-donations/

https://www.vbgardens.org/support/commemorative-donations/

https://www.vbgardens.org/support/commemorative-donations/

http://www.hoytarboretum.org/support-hoyt/commemorative-donations/

For example, from Hoyt Arboretum:

"Silver Leaf Stewards

The Silver Leaf Stewards program is the perfect way to honor your family or pay tribute to someone who has touched your life in a significant way. With your tax-deductible gift, a metal leaf plaque will be installed on a rock wall in the arboretum engraved with your honoree’s name."

Comment: I'd call the inscription a _commemorative plaque_.

Comment: I like the idea of a "commemorative dedication", but would like to permit a phrase, poetry, quote, or random individual thought on my dedication wall.   Does the usage of the word *commemorate* (in general practice) allow for this flexibility?

Comment: Yes, I think the word commemorate absolutely allows the use of any sort of text or even picture… poetry or a quote in addition to a name would be almost expected…

Comment: So far I'm leaning this way, thank you for your help. (will see what the rest of my team thinks)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try "personal etching".   M-W definition for etching:

2: the art of producing pictures or designs by printing from an etched metal plate.